# How to execute any git command (like git clean) on a particular location on remote machine via ssh?

Tags: git, ssh

I am automating a process in which I am able login to remote server via SSH with passwordless authentication.
Now, I need to know can we able to execute git clean command via SSH from source machine or not.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: yes you can issue git command from source machine something like this `ssh username@remotehostname cd /particular/path && git clean`

Answer (score 1):

You can use following format to execute any commands remotely:
ssh user@hostname "your commands"